# How can I add Edit Android Manifest Meta Data in Expo Managed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I add this meta data to react native expo managed app

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.ar.core"  android:value="required"  />
```

Answer (score 3):

Hello to edit a metadata with expo please create a new plugin.

android-manifest.plugin.js

```js
const { withAndroidManifest } = require("@expo/config-plugins");

module.exports = function androiManifestPlugin(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, async (config) => {
    let androidManifest = config.modResults.manifest;

    androidManifest.application[0]["meta-data"] = androidManifest.application[0]["meta-data"].map(res => {
        if (res.$["android:name"] === "com.google.ar.core") {
          res.$["android:value"] = "required";
        }

        return res;
    });


    return config;
  });
};
```

You can then add this plugin like this in `app.json`:

````js
    "plugins": [
      ...
      "./android-manifest.plugin.js"
    ],```
````